# Find all complex solutions of z of the equation $2z+3\bar z=5$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having trouble starting this problem, I'm suppose to solve for the variable $z$, where $z$ is a complex number ($z = x + yi$) and $\bar z$ is a complex conjugate ($\bar z = x - yi$) the question is...

"Find all complex solutions of $z$ of the equation $2 z+3{\bar z}=5$"

This is my worked solution so far;

$2z+3\bar z=5$

$2(x + yi) + 3(x - yi) = 5$

$2x + 2yi + 3x - 3yi = 5$

$5x - yi = 5$

At the last part, I'm not sure about how I solve for $x$ and $y$, and how I use the variables to solve for $z$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Let $z=x+iy $...

Comment: Hi, sorry about the miscommunication, I wanted to quote the questions to show that there is nothing else related to the problem. I'll be sure to phrase my question more carefully next time. Apologies for the formatting as well, I'm also new, so I wasn't sure how to format the equation properly.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply
$$
\eqalign{
  & 2z + 3\bar z = 5\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 2\left( {x + iy} \right) + 3\left( {x - iy} \right) = 5\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 5x - iy = 5 + i0\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  x = 1 \hfill \cr 
  y = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad z = 1 \cr} 
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the answer. I'm just wondering why the 5 at the end of the equation is being treated as a complex number, I got to the third line without having $+i0$.

Comment: in the complex field a real number is always to be read as $+i0$

Answer (score 0):

well I won't post a direct answer but take $w=2z+3\overline{z}$ as we know that $w$ is real we have the equation $ w = \overline{w} $ , and observe what I am suggesting you to ponder over !

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks! What if we had something, say, for example, $2z+3i{\bar z}=0$, where $w = 0$, it would be hard to tell because you end up with $2x + 2iy+ 2ix + 2y = 0$

Comment: well i meant that any equation of the above form can have only real solutions :)  to solve your further query ill post another comment

Comment: try substituting $z=re^{\iota \theta}$ you will reach the answer yourself

Answer (score 0):

From the given, we have,
$$2z+3\bar z=5,\>\>\>\>\>\>2\bar z+ 3z=5$$

Eliminate $\bar z$ in the system of equations above to obtain the solution $z=1$.